# El localStorage guarda un valor siempre, a pesar de que lo borren

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Estoy usando localStorage en JavaScript. Al momento de guardar, se guarda todo bien y se actualiza correctamente; al borrar todo del arreglo, en el momento se elimina del DOM, pero al recargar la página, vuelve a aparecer. Solo me pasa con un solo elemento.
Les adjunto el código:

```
const mascotaInput = document.querySelector('#mascota');
const propietarioInput = document.querySelector('#propietario');
const telefonoInput = document.querySelector('#telefono');
const fechaInput = document.querySelector('#fecha');
const horaInput = document.querySelector('#hora');
const sintomasInput = document.querySelector('#sintomas');
const btnEnviar = document.querySelector('.btn')

const formulario = document.querySelector('#nueva-cita')

const contenedorCitas = document.querySelector('#citas')

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    admnistrarCitas.citas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('citas'));
    ui.añadirCita(admnistrarCitas );
        })
// -------------------------------------------------------------CLASESSSS


class Citas {
    constructor() {
        this.citas = [];
    }



    agregarCita(cita) {
        this.citas = [...this.citas, cita]

        console.log(this.citas)
    }


    eliminarCita(id){
        this.citas = this.citas.filter(cita => cita.id !== id);
    }
}

class UI {
    imprimirAlerta(mensaje, tipo) {
        // Creamos el div que va a contener el mensjae

        const divMensaje = document.createElement('div');

        divMensaje.classList.add('text-center', 'alert', 'd-block', 'col-12');

        // Agregar clase en base al tipo de error

        if (tipo === 'error') {
            divMensaje.classList.add('alert-danger');

        } else {
            divMensaje.classList.add('alert-success')
        }


        //MEnsaje de error

        divMensaje.textContent = mensaje;


        // Agregar al DOM

        document.querySelector('#contenido').insertBefore(divMensaje, document.querySelector('.agregar-cita'))


        setTimeout(() => {
            divMensaje.remove();
        }, 3000);
    }


    añadirCita({ citas }) {

        this.limpiarHTML();
        citas.forEach(cita => {

            const { mascota, propietario, telefono, fecha, hora, sintomas, id } = cita;
            const divCita = document.createElement('div');
            divCita.classList.add('cita', 'p-3')
            divCita.dataset.id = id;


            // Scripting de los elementos

            const mascotaP = document.createElement('h2');
            mascotaP.classList.add('card-title', 'font-wight-bolder');
            mascotaP.textContent = mascota;

            const propietarioP = document.createElement('p');
            propietarioP.innerHTML = `<span class="font-wight-bolder"> Propiertario: </span> ${propietario}`

            const telefonoP = document.createElement('p')
            telefonoP.innerHTML = `<span class="font-wight-bolder"> Telefono: </span> ${telefono}`

            const fechaP = document.createElement('p')
            fechaP.innerHTML = `<span class="font-wight-bolder"> Fecha: </span> ${fecha}`

            const horaP = document.createElement('p')
            horaP.innerHTML = `<span class="font-wight-bolder"> Hora: </span> ${hora}`

            const sintomasP = document.createElement('p')
            sintomasP.innerHTML = `<span class="font-wight-bolder"> Sintomas: </span> ${sintomas}`
            // BTN ELMINAR
            
             const bntEliminar = document.createElement('button')
             bntEliminar.classList.add('btn','btn-danger','mr-2')
             bntEliminar.innerHTML = 'Eliminar <svg class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 14l2-2m0 0l2-2m-2 2l-2-2m2 2l2 2m7-2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>'

                bntEliminar.onclick= () => eliminarCita(id);


                // BTN Editar

                const btnEditar = document.createElement('button')
                btnEditar.classList.add('btn','btn-info');
                btnEditar.innerHTML = `Editar <svg class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15.232 5.232l3.536 3.536m-2.036-5.036a2.5 2.5 0 113.536 3.536L6.5 21.036H3v-3.572L16.732 3.732z"></path></svg>`

                btnEditar.onclick = () => editarEleccion(cita);

            // Agregar parrafo a div cita
            divCita.appendChild(mascotaP);
            divCita.appendChild(propietarioP);
            divCita.appendChild(telefonoP);
            divCita.appendChild(fechaP);
            divCita.appendChild(horaP);
            divCita.appendChild(sintomasP);
            divCita.appendChild(bntEliminar);
            divCita.appendChild(btnEditar)

            // Agregar cita al HTML

            contenedorCitas.appendChild(divCita);

            sincronizarStorage();
        });

    }

    limpiarHTML(){
        while(contenedorCitas.firstChild){
            contenedorCitas.removeChild(contenedorCitas.firstChild)
        }
    }
}


// Instanciar citqas

const ui = new UI();
const admnistrarCitas = new Citas();


// -------------------------------------------------------- EVENT LISTENERS
eventListeners();
function eventListeners() {
    mascotaInput.addEventListener('input', datosCita);
    propietarioInput.addEventListener('input', datosCita);
    telefonoInput.addEventListener('input', datosCita);
    fechaInput.addEventListener('input', datosCita);
    horaInput.addEventListener('input', datosCita);
    sintomasInput.addEventListener('input', datosCita);

    formulario.addEventListener('submit', nuevaCita)
    
}

// ------------------------------------------------------ FUNCIONES

const citasObj = {
    mascota: '',
    propietario: '',
    telefono: '',
    fecha: '',
    hora: '',
    sintomas: ''
}
// aGREGA DATOS AL OBJ DE CITAS
function datosCita(e) {
    citasObj[e.target.name] = e.target.value;

    // console.log(citasObj)
}

// Validar y agrega nueva cita
function nuevaCita(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Extraer info from objec cita

    const { mascota, propietario, telefono, fecha, hora, sintomas } = citasObj;


    // Validar
    if (mascota === '' || propietario === '' || telefono === '' || fecha === '' || hora === '' || sintomas === '') {
        ui.imprimirAlerta('Todos los campos son obligatorios', 'error');
        return;// ESt es para que no continue ejecutando en caso de que sea true la de arriba
    }

    // Generar un id para cadad cita

    citasObj.id = Date.now();

    // Crear nueva cita


    admnistrarCitas.agregarCita({ ...citasObj })


    //Reiniciar VAlores
    ui.imprimirAlerta('Se ha añadido correctamente')
    formulario.reset();
    // Reiniciar el objeto tambien

    reiniciarObjeto();


    // Mostrar el HTML

    ui.añadirCita(admnistrarCitas);

    console.log(citasObj)


}


// --------------------------------------------------------


// ------------------------------ funciones


function reiniciarObjeto() {
    citasObj.mascota = '';
    citasObj.propietario = '';
    citasObj.fecha = '';
    citasObj.hora = '';
    citasObj.sintomas = '';
    citasObj.telefono = '';
}


function sincronizarStorage(){
    localStorage.setItem('citas', JSON.stringify(admnistrarCitas.citas))
}

function eliminarCita(id)
{

    admnistrarCitas.eliminarCita(id);

    ui.imprimirAlerta('La cita se eliminó correctamente')
   
    ui.añadirCita(admnistrarCitas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto el problema, la solucion es, al momento de eliminar las citas invocar nuevamente la funcion de sincronizarStorage()